# Training Keras LSTM with 3D input

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I am trying to use [NFL tracking data](https://www.kaggle.com/c/nfl-big-data-bowl-2021/overview/description) to predict offensive yardage results at the end of a play. To do this my input will give train_x containing an array of tracking data for 1 play paired with a float in y_train that has the yardage outcome.

How should I arrange my data to train an LSTM model? [I have been trying to use this tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/)
but it doesn't use a 3d input. Can an LSTM model handle what I am trying to do?

So far I have tried this:

```
def isolatePlay(data, gameNum, playNum):
    MAX_X_YARDS = 120
    MAX_Y_YARDS = 53.3
    d = data[data['gameId'] == gameNum]
    d = d[d['playId'] == playNum].fillna(0)
    #normalize x ,y...
    sub = d[["x","y", "s", "a", "dis", "o", "dir"]].to_numpy()
    norm = Normalizer().fit(sub)

    return norm.transform(sub)



print("creating ML training, test, and validation datasets")
first = True
for  rows in plays.itertuples():
    #print(getattr(rows, 'gameId'), gameMax)
    play = isolatePlay(week, getattr(rows, 'gameId'), getattr(rows, 'playId'))
    if (first):
        x = [play]
        y = [[getattr(rows, 'offensePlayResult')]]
        first = False
    else:
        x.append(play)
        y.append([getattr(rows, 'offensePlayResult')])
        
train_x, test_x, train_y, test_y = train_test_split(np.array(x), np.array(y), test_size=0.3)
test_x, val_x, test_y, val_y = train_test_split(test_x, test_y, test_size=0.5)
print("x data:[0]", train_x[0])
print("x data:[1]", train_x[1])

print("ML Dataset Preparation Complete")



 # create the model
embedding_vecor_length = 32
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(train_x, train_y, validation_data=(val_x, val_y), epochs=3, batch_size=64)
print(model.summary())

# Final evaluation of the model
scores = model.evaluate(test_x, test_y, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

but that has not worked

```
ValueError: Failed to convert a NumPy array to a Tensor (Unsupported object type list).
```

I figure it has something to do with reshaping my input to the form [samples, timestep, features] but I'm not sure what that means for 3d input. The timesteps are within the tracking data and there is a different number of features than rows of tracking data (~1500 rows per 1 result). Any references for neural net projects involving a similar data dimension as the input would be appreciated as I have been having trouble finding any.

The plays I am passing in look like this.

```
shape (1296, 7)
normalized tracking data
 [[ 1.50585604e-01  9.04000519e-02  3.59760829e-03 ...  3.51645923e-04
   7.88471309e-01  5.89439716e-01]
 [ 2.58656328e-01  1.55707513e-01  1.74663657e-03 ...  5.13716639e-04
   5.48443883e-01  7.79770486e-01]
 [ 1.55811974e-01  1.32418437e-01  1.44941371e-04 ...  0.00000000e+00
   2.80084706e-01  9.37944603e-01]
 ...
 [ 6.18136846e-01  5.88895155e-03  1.02887429e-02 ...  1.35378197e-03
   3.76622143e-01  6.89278088e-01]
 [ 3.58395476e-01  1.52762473e-01  2.09288701e-02 ...  2.10202625e-03
   6.65474093e-01  6.36319903e-01]
 [ 9.97562556e-01  3.33489046e-03  6.60523466e-02 ...  6.56220381e-03
  -1.07577112e-02 -1.07577112e-02]]
shape (832, 7)
normalized tracking data
 [[ 2.37484336e-01  6.72201854e-02  1.79624884e-03 ...  1.26496397e-04
   8.06945816e-01  5.36572417e-01]
 [ 5.23191345e-01  1.45525783e-01  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00
   5.63912408e-01  6.22170278e-01]
 [ 2.46464025e-01  2.66599975e-02  3.22175196e-04 ...  8.05437991e-05
   3.36028730e-01  9.08641445e-01]
 ...
 [ 4.92441881e-01  7.33912651e-03  2.67000124e-02 ...  2.70151896e-03
   6.38594057e-01  5.90552045e-01]
 [ 4.38248969e-01  6.56688483e-02  1.62183495e-02 ...  1.63509245e-03
   6.60179626e-01  6.06221575e-01]
 [ 9.97770139e-01  1.13661959e-02  6.40144152e-02 ...  6.45599926e-03
  -9.09295670e-03 -9.09295670e-03]]
```

Comment: which line generating an error ?

Comment: model.fit @Andrey

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a list of arrays as an input. Convert it to array:

```
train_x = np.array(train_x)
train_y = np.array(train_y)
```